# Create survey that redirects to sidebar menu customized to answers

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, customization, menus, plugin-recommendation

EXPLAINED:

I want to create a survey for my users about who they are and what they most want to get out of my services. After the survey is completed I would like the users to be redirected to a page with a side menu customized to the answers that they chose.

Such as: If they said they were a salesperson, I want the content that they are being redirected to be about that. And let's say they said they are on my site for information about "Documents" "Organizing" and "Files" then I want the three sidebar menu options to say that.

Basically I am asking if there is a plugin or two to accomplish this or what would be my first step to code this?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The wordpress plugin archive offers a lot of options for this kind of topic. You should read the explanations and documentation of the plugin. Here are the plugins I would recommend to you;

https://wordpress.org/plugins/formidable/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/quiz-master-next/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-polls/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/social-polls-by-opinionstage/
https://wordpress.org/plugins/yop-poll/

Comment: Wow! Thank you. I'll check them out, I'm just having trouble connecting it so that it customizes the menu followed by the answer.